# OpenCL error about get_global_id

Tags: opencl

My program, I have set

```
size_t global_item_size = 12000; 
size_t local_item_size = 600; 
cl_mem arr_M_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 12000 * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);    
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and my kernel:

```
__kernel void mykernel(__global int* arrM)
{
   int n = get_global_id(0);
   arrM[n] = n;
}
```

But my result has an error, I use a loop and print `arrM` after copying from device to host, and my result

```
arrM[0] = 0
arrM[1] = 0
arrM[2] = 1
arrM[3] = 0
arrM[4] = 2
arrM[5] = 0
arrM[6] = 3
...
arrM[11998] = 5999
arrM[11999] = 0
```

Can you help me solve it?

Comment: I set 20 work_groups, but when i get get_group_id(0), maximum is 9 but get_num_groups(0) = 20. I don't understand what problem's happening

Comment: `local_item_size` (set to 600) is perhaps larger than your device can handle. Try passing NULL instead and let the runtime determine the work group size.

Comment: work-group-size is 1024, it run well but result is error. thank for your comment

Comment: @AnNguyen did you make sure to use cl_int everywhere you used int on the host side as I mentioned in my answer? If you notice the "high bytes" of your array are zero and you only write half the elements you wanted - it indicates something with the sizes of types is off.   Also - let us rule out that n on the kernel is coming up with all integers it should be - printf them so we can observe odd numbers between 0-11999.

Comment: @AnNguyen your sourcecode had the error that I mentioned - you mixed cl_ulong and cl_int

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is quite easy if you didn't omit anything in your posting - you forgot to set the argument to the kernel - the buffer arr_M_obj.

[Take a look here for the function used to set the argument](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html).

```
cl_mem arr_M_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, nmax * NMAX * sizeof(cl_ulong), NULL, &ret);
__kernel void PatternBranching(__global int4* arrlmer, __global int* arrMscore, __global int4* arrM, int k, int l, int n1, int sqelenght, int a1)
 PatternBranching(arr_lmer_obj, arr_Mscore_obj, arr_M_obj, k, l, n1, sqelength, a1)
```

notice anything bad about the declaration of arr_Mscore_obj and the signature? Change the cl_ulong to cl_int

Comment: thank you very much, sorry my posting is not enought my code, i have set argument in my code. 
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&arr_M_obj);

Comment: @AnNguyen use cl types in the host code - ie cl_int

Comment: i have repaired cl_int but it still has error. I tried create a new project by OpenCL Code Builder generating and change some variables and it's fine.

Comment: my source code has error: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8mSc9Fjs4dYTXV5ZFp3T05PRk0&authuser=0